# RelativeLayout is not visible with ViewPager in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-relativelayout

I want to make visible top part of the screen via `RelativeLayout` to display two `TextView` verticaly and below display `ViewPager` but somehow `ViewPager` **fits all screen space.**

How to fix it? Thanks!

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="android.apps.abc.company.tracks.Activities.UnitDetailsActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUnitName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Device"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDriverName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="User"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip_ud"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="#33b5e5"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"
                android:textColor="#fff" />


        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You need to use only one Relative layout and set viewpager below to second textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
 >

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUnitName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Device"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDriverName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="User"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewUnitName"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rel_main"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip_ud"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="#33b5e5"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"
                android:textColor="#fff" />


        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewUnitName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Device"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDriverName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip_ud"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />


</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps you...if you need any help you can ask

Answer (score 1):

you can also make this change and no need to include extra relative parent view group.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="android.apps.abc.company.tracks.Activities.UnitDetailsActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/rlSubParent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewUnitName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Device"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDriverName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlSubParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip_ud"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#33b5e5"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   You can make using only one relative layout. 
   <RelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"                
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewUnitName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Device"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewDriverName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewUnitName"
                    android:text="User"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewUnitName"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewDriverName"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip_ud"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:background="#33b5e5"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />


            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        </RelativeLayout>
```